# Test if method is called from and AJAX request or from PhpUnit

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2, phpunit, ajax-request

I've started implementing unit tests on my current project.

While all unit test currently pass, due to convenience, I made a change to the `jsonResponse` method to also send json headers. This helps me see the json response as a tree in the Chrome console.

Now the unit tests are failing due to

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at [fullPath]/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:134)

Digging deeper, I found that this can be fixed by adding `@runInSeparateProcess` in the docBlocks.

But this just leads to:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Configuration' not found in - on line 365
>     PHP Stack trace:
>     PHP   1. {main}() -:0

This is one of my json methods (this is called at the end of several methods which are called through AJAX requests):

```
/**
 * Helper function to print a json encoded success message back to the frontend.
 *
 * @param array $returnData
 *
 * @return bool
 *
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
public function returnJsonSuccess($returnData = [])
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(
        [
            "success" => true,
            "data"    => $returnData,
        ]
    );
    return true;
}
```

So, cutting to the chase, how can i make this work properly?

One of my options is to detect if the method is called from a unit test and conditionally send the headers only if it's called normally. I'm thinking easiest way is to define an environment variable or a constant in the bootstrap file and check for that in my `BaseController`.

Is there a cleaner way of getting my unit tests to work again while also keeping the json headers sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself with:

```
/**
 * Helper function to print a json encoded success message back to extJs.
 *
 * @param array $returnData
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function returnJsonSuccess($returnData = [])
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
    }
    echo json_encode(
        [
            "success" => true,
            "data"    => $returnData,
        ]
    );
    return true;
}
```

ZendFramework, using the `Request` class, can detect if the call is made from an AJAX request or not. This way, I only send the headers if there's an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you have two possible solutions:

1. Setup an environment key in your phpunit bootstrap file and check if that server key exists
2. Use a variable in your class that will be disabled in your `setUp` method

I hope that this helps